# Debugging error from column in table using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, sql, file-geodatabase

I have an a File Geodatabase Feature Class it has some features. The small data was added below.

This table contains 11 million data. There are errors in the project_ID part. Some of the sample data has 13 letters. Some are less than 12 letters, some are even or null.( I said letter because it is text format not number).

I'm looking for a method where I can debug these errors using ArcGIS Pro?

project_ID is a 12 digit number and indicates the information code for a building.

| Project_ID |
| --- |
| 551830037624 |
| 551830037624 |
| 551830037625 |
| null |
| 551830037627 |
| 551830037 |
| 551830037629 |
| 551830037630 |
| 551830037631 |
| 551830037631 |
| 551830037633 |
| 551830037634 |
| 5518300376344 |
| 551830037636 |
| 551830037637 |
| null |
| 5518300376 |
| 551830037640 |
| 55183003 |
| 551830037642 |
| 551830037643 |
| 55183037644 |
| 551830037645 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [select by attribute tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/select-layer-by-attribute.htm) to select the erroneous rows.

You could select text in your ID column where it is a specific value, such as your null:

[image: Select null]

You can select rows based upon the number of text characters, for example:

[image: Select by length]

In fact you can select rows in multiple ways using complex logic, you need only explore the examples on the [Help page](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/mapping/navigation/sql-reference-for-elements-used-in-query-expressions.htm).