# Filtering characters in between text in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro

I have a dataset which I also mentioned in [Debugging error from a column in a table using ArcGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/421611/debugging-error-from-a-column-in-a-table-using-arcgis/422002#422002) that includes a field named project ID. The project ID's class is text.

- The first 2 characters are city code
- From three to six (4 characters) is town code
- And the last 6 characters are building codes.

So some buildings are counted in both towns. Therefore their city code(first 2 characters) and building codes(last 6 characters) are identical.

I want to filter the project_ID's based on the first 2 characters and the last 6 characters being the identical.

what I mean the same;

```
551830037629
551832037629

551835367485
551835367485
```

In this number, they have the same first 2 characters and last 6 characters but in the middle 4 characters, the town codes are different.

So the filter should choose only the first 2 and the last 6 characters were the same.

How can I solve or query this?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking, so you may want to [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/425741/edit) your question and try to clarify. That said, you can for instance set a definition query on the layer that goes like `SUBSTRING(PROJECT_ID,3,4)='1830'`.

Comment: Given that it's impossible for two characters to be equal to six, I suggest you [Edit]  the Question  to give a complete example if what you mean, with features that both meet and do not meet your criteria.

Comment: Okay, I edited the question I hope it is way clearer now.

Comment: You can make a compound query of substring or a single query of concatenated substring. eEther it going to have awful performance without a covering index.

Comment: Could you tell us what you mean by *Filtering*?

Comment: First I want to choose where the first 2 and last 6 characters are identical(as field values, not themselves) and then I will delete one of them. No matter which one was deleted.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Answer (score 1):

I think I would do this:

1. Add a new textfield
2. Use the field calculator to set the value of the new field to the project ID, except characters 3–6: `!project_id![0:2] + !project_id![6:12]`
3. Use the *Delete Identical* tool to delete identical records, based on the field you just calculated